# Microsoft Speech Object Library - Client or server?

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech

I know you can use Microsoft Speech Object Library for asp.net sites.  But does that depend on the client, or does it come from the server?  I want to know if the client is dependent at all on using it like Macs or Linux?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SpeechLib;
using System.Threading;

namespace ARIES.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static SpVoice speach;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            speach = new SpVoice();
            //speach.Speak("This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test ", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
            speach.Speak("This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
            //speach.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);

            return View();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            speach.Pause();
            speach = new SpVoice();
            speach.Speak("Stopped", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the object in your server side code or through javascript on the client?

If you are only using it on the server then it doesn't need to exist on the client machines but the sound will play on the server, not the client.

If you are using it through javascript it is required on the clients and you are also probably restricted to internet explorer only.

Comment: I am making calls on the server on page load, and an ajax call.  The ajax call calls the "Stop" method and stops the sound being played.  I hear the sound but I wonder if that is because I am running the project on my local.  This worked in Firefox.

Comment: yes, you are hearing the sound because you are running the site locally so the speech object being invoked in on your machine. A remote caller wouldn't hear anything.

Comment: Got yea, nothing around it I guess.